# To find data from maximum date to last 12 month in SQL redshift

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I have a string column(year_to_month) in the table with value as YYYYMM format. I have to find data between maximum year_to_month to last 12 months. I have tried below code, but it is not working and picking some random garbage value for the day as there is no day value present in year_to_month

```
  select * from Table
  where to_date between to_date(year_to_month,'mm') between max(to_date(year_to_month,'mm'))-12 and 
  max(to_date(year_to_month,'mm'))
```

---

```
sample data
201911
201910
201909
201812
201802
201805
```

I am using Amazon redshift database and running query in workbench

Can anyone please help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but your requirement is unclear. Given the above sample data, what results were you wanting?

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you have not accepted any answer but you already asked five questions. Please remember to accept the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient:

```
select *
from Table
where to_date >= to_char(year_to_month,'yyyymm')
```

You don't have to compare to the maximum `year_to_month` in the data, because you are going to get all those values anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my approach:

```
select newdate
from (select to_date(year_to_month,'yyyymm') as newdate from sample) t
where newdate
between
(
select to_date(year_to_month,'yyyymm') - interval '12' month
from
(
  select t.*, row_number() over (order by year_to_month desc) as rn
  from sample t
)
where rn = 1
)
and 
(
select to_date(year_to_month,'yyyymm') 
from
(
  select t.*, row_number() over (order by year_to_month desc) as rn
  from sample t
)
where rn = 1
)
```

**The clarification:**

1, I used the below subquery to select the max date.

```
select ...
from
(
  select t.*, row_number() over (order by year_to_month desc) as rn
  from sample t
)
where rn = 1
```

2, I used the below query to get the date before 12 months

```
select to_date(year_to_month,'yyyymm') - interval '12' month
```

---

Test Result (I tested it in Oracle 18c. Let me know if you meet any issue in Amazon Redshift):

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff6011456b170fcef1b8258e11c27f6b)